# Proving sequence $(\frac{e^n}{n^{100}})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I can see that since $e^n$ grows asymptotically faster than the polynomial $n^{100}$ as n approaches to $\infty$, $e^n>0$ and $n^{100}>0$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^n}{n^{100}}=\infty$.
But I'm stuck on proving the convergence of the sequence $(\frac{e^n}{n^{100}})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Could anyone guides me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean divergence surely?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown They may be using the loose sense of convergence in which if the reciprocal of a sequence goes to 0, then the original sequence "goes to infinity".

Answer (score 2):

Don't be impressed by the exponent $100$.

$$\dfrac{e^n}{n^{100}}=\left(\frac{e^{n/100}}n\right)^{100}=100^{-100}\left(\frac{e^{n/100}}{n/100}\right)^{100}\propto\left(\frac{e^{m}}{m}\right)^{100}$$ which essentially behaves like $\dfrac{e^m}m$.

Comment: Very nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{e^n}{n^{100}}$

Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to e >1$

So by ratio test for sequences,the limit is plus infinity.

Comment: Best way of course!

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be any fixed positive integer (e.g. 100, in your example).

$$\dfrac{e^n}{n^k}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^\infty n^i/i!}{n^k} > \dfrac{n^{k+1}/(k+1)!}{n^k} = \dfrac{n}{(k+1)!}\to\infty $$

A single term of the series for $e^n$ dominates the power function $n^k$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative by l'Hospital

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^{100}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{100x^{99}}=\ldots=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{100!x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{100!}=\infty$$

therefore

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{e^n}{n^{100}}=\infty$$